# JPA 2.0: Mapping between three entities

Tags: jpa-2.0

I want to implement the following relationship using JPA 2.0. [Entity Diagram](http://oi35.tinypic.com/fu5emc.jpg)
In a few words: A user can have several roles in a group.
Is there a convenient way to achieve this? A code example would be nice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The entity diagram is not opening!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Users implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 10)
@Column(name = "id_usuario")
private Integer idUsuario;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 80)
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "Users")
private Collection<NzSistemaControl> nzSistemaControlCollection;
```

Roles

```
public class Roles implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_rol")
private Integer idRol;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "Roles")
private Collection<NzSistemaControl> nzSistemaControlCollection;
```

Relationship table

```
public class SistemaControl implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
protected NzSistemaControlPK nzSistemaControlPK;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario", referencedColumnName = "id_usuario_sistema", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Users user;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_rol", referencedColumnName = "id_rol", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Roles roles;
```

RelationShipPK

```
public class NzSistemaControlPK implements Serializable {
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_usuario")
private int idUsuario;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_rol")
private int idRol;
```